# Оператор all в sql работает не так как ожидается

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Нужно сформировать  запрос, выводящий фамилии руководителей, у которых все подчиненные получают больше $2500
Вот мое решение но оно выводит не правильный ответ 
Нужно использовать операторы all, any, in

```
select * 
        from emp e
        where 2500 >= all(select sal from emp where e.empno = emp.mgr);
```

Ниже скрипт на создание базы

```
drop table Emp
;

drop table Dept
;

drop table Salgrade
;

CREATE TABLE Dept(  -- îïèñàíèå ïîäðàçäåëåíèÿ 
   deptno NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,  -- ¹ ïîäðàçäåëåíèÿ 
   dname VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,  -- íàçâàíèå ïîäðàçäåëåíèÿ 
   loc VARCHAR(13), -- ìåñòîïîëîæåíèå ïîäðàçäåëåíèÿ 
   CONSTRAINT dept_pk PRIMARY KEY (deptno), 
   CONSTRAINT dept_naem_uk UNIQUE (dname) 
)
;

CREATE TABLE Emp( -- îïèñàíèå ñîòðóäíèêîâ ïîäðàçäåëåíèé 
  empno NUMBER(4) NOT NULL, -- ¹ ñîòðóäíèêà 
  ename VARCHAR(20), -- èìÿ ñîòðóäíèêà 
  job VARCHAR(9), -- äîëæíîñòü ñîòðóäíèêà 
  mgr NUMBER(4), -- ¹ íà÷àëüíèêà ñîòðóäíèêà 
  hiredate DATE, -- äàòà ïðèåìà íà ðàáîòó ñîòðóäíèêà  
  sal NUMBER(7, 2), -- ç/ï ñîòðóäíèêà 
  comm NUMBER(7, 2), -- ïðåìèÿ ñîòðóäíèêà 
  deptno NUMBER(2),  -- ¹ ïîäðàçäåëåíèÿ, ãäå ðàáîòàåò ñîòðóäíèê 
  CONSTRAINT emp_pk PRIMARY KEY (empno), 
  CONSTRAINT emp_deptno_fk FOREIGN KEY (deptno) REFERENCES Dept (deptno) 
)
;

CREATE TABLE Salgrade( -- îïèñàíèå äèàïàçîíà ç/ï äëÿ ðàçëè÷íûõ ãðóïï ñîòðóäíèêîâ 
  grade NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,  -- ¹ ãðóïïû ñîòðóäíèêîâ 
  minsal NUMBER, -- min ç/ï 
  hisal NUMBER,  -- max ç/ï 
  CONSTRAINT salgrade_pk PRIMARY KEY (grade) 
)
;

ALTER TABLE Emp ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Self FOREIGN KEY (mgr) REFERENCES Emp (empno) ON DELETE CASCADE
;

commit



INSERT INTO Dept  VALUES (10,'ACCOUNTING','NEW_YORK')
;

INSERT INTO Dept VALUES (20,'RESEARCH','DALLAS')
;

INSERT INTO Dept VALUES (30,'SALES','CHICAGO')
;

INSERT INTO Dept VALUES (40,'OPERATIONS','BOSTON')
;

INSERT INTO Dept VALUES (50,'RESEARCH2','HONKONG')
;

INSERT INTO Dept VALUES (60,'SALES2','HONKONG')
;

INSERT INTO Dept VALUES (100,'SALES3','NEW_YORK')
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',null, TO_DATE('2011-11-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),5000,null,10)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,TO_DATE('2011-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 2850,null,30)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,TO_DATE('2011-06-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1500,null,10)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,TO_DATE('2011-04-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 2975,null,20)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,TO_DATE('2011-09-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1250,1400,30)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,TO_DATE('2011-02-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1600,300,30)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,TO_DATE('2011-09-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1500,0,30)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,TO_DATE('2011-12-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 950,null,30)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,TO_DATE('2011-02-22', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1250,500,30)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,TO_DATE('2011-12-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 3000,null,20)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,TO_DATE('2010-12-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 800,null,20)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,TO_DATE('2012-12-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 3000,null,20)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,TO_DATE('2013-01-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1100,null,20)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,TO_DATE('2012-01-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1300,null,10)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (8000,'JACKIE CHAN','SALESMAN',7839,TO_DATE('2011-09-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 2250,1700,60)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (8001,'JET LI','SALESMAN',8000,TO_DATE('2011-02-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 2600,600,60)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (8002,'BRUCE LEE','SALESMAN',8000,TO_DATE('2011-09-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 2500,null,60)
;

INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (8003,'DR NO','ANALYST', 7839, TO_DATE('2011-09-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 2500,null,null)
;

commit
```

Comment: _но оно выводит не правильный ответ_ - а какой ответ, почему он неправильный, и какой, по вашему мнению, должен быть правильный?

Comment: Мне интересно почему оператор all не работает, как он должен работать.
Парильный вывод это 2 человека JONES  и JACKIE CHAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы перепутали направление больше/меньше.

Зарплата >= 2500, когда 2500 <= Зарплата.

Ну и во имя избежания неоднозначностей алиасы должны быть у всех таблиц.

```
select * 
from emp e
where 2500 <= all(select sal from emp e2 where e.empno = e2.mgr)
```

**UPD**

Приведенный мной выше запрос не работает, т.к. выводит еще и тех, у кого нет подчиненных. Исправленный вариант:

```
select * 
from emp e
where 2500 <= all(select sal from emp e2 where e.empno = e2.mgr)
  and exists (select sal from emp e3 where e.empno = e3.mgr)
```

Comment: В таком случае должны вывестись двое, а выводятся почти все
[скриншот вывода](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l8AUQUc1E7BtWFoLzlx0U2Mhdgz_vTfK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Да, забыл, что all возвращает истину, если подзапрос не вернул ни одной строки. Нужно добавить в where `and exists (select sal from emp e3 where e.empno = e3.mgr)`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM emp e
 WHERE e.empno IN (SELECT e0.mgr
                     FROM emp e0
                    GROUP BY e0.mgr
                   HAVING sum(e0.sal) >= 2500);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо @Uzkesh, я справил ваш запрос. Вывел правильный результат

Answer (score 0):

Я подправил ответ @Uzkesh, спасибо большое.

```
SELECT *
  FROM emp e
 WHERE e.empno IN (SELECT e0.mgr
                     FROM emp e0
                    GROUP BY e0.mgr
                   HAVING min(e0.sal) >= 2500);
```

```
select * 
from emp 
    where empno in  
        (select mgr from emp m where   m.mgr = e.empno and 
         2500 <= (select min(sal) from emp where m.mgr = mgr )) ;
```